# VS Code stops letting me collapse code and navigate to definition when working in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I've been having a really weird issue with VS Code. After using it for an undetermined amount of time, I'm unable to collapse code and navigate to definition.  The arrow indicators in the left margin for collapsing code disappear and I can't seem to get them to come back.  Closing the file doesn't work, and restarting the app doesn't work either.  The only thing that works is a complete system restart. The same thing happens with ctrl+clicking a class name expecting it to navigate to definition but it doesn't.

I thought at first it was probably an extension I installed so I uninstalled all my extensions, restarted the app and now the collapse icons don't show up at all.  I'm working in VueJS and think it might have something to do with *.vue extensions but I'm not sure.

Comment: It seems to be certain files as well which is making this even more random.  After a restart I tried a few files. First file was fine, second file didn't show the collapse arrows, 3rd and 4th worked fine.  Why would this issue be so intermittent like this?

Comment: This happens to my .ts files! .vue files are fine. Why is that? Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You need [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) for pretty much any functionality in *.vue files, and [Vue Peek](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dariofuzinato.vue-peek) for Ctrl+Clicking paths